# How can I reproduce the following hyperbolic paraboloid graph?

Tags: plotting

I need to reproduce the following figure:
[image]

I tried graphing a paraboloid and then using the function Cube[] to insersect graphs but its a disaster.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, MeshStyle -> White, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot :)